# Inverse of ._meta to get Class of Reverse FK

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have a class, to get the FK class, I can do:

```
MasterModel = Model._meta.get_field('master').rel.to
```

Given a MasterModel, how would I get the reverse FK? Something like:

```
Model = MasterModel.???
```

Currently, to get around this, I am doing:

```
    if item_type == 'TV Episode' or item_type == 'Movie':
        InstanceModel = Catalog
    elif item_type == 'TV Season':
        InstanceModel = CollectionInstance
    elif item_type == 'TV Series':
        InstanceModel = TVSeriesInstance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used _meta.get_related_objects() to retrieve reverse fk relations.
For example:

```
   for robject in Model._meta.get_all_related_objects():
            if robject is not None:
                q = Q(**{"%s__id" % robject.field.name: Model.objects.get(id=1).id})
                print robject.model.objects.filter(q)
```